# Why does QGIS cloud custom dbsearch zoom to 0,0 point in Atlantic?

Tags: coordinate-system, qgis-cloud

I have a QGIS project with several layers including OpenStreetMap and Mapbox Satellite. These have a CRS of EPSG:3857.  The other layers were defined in postgres/postgis with a CRS of EPSG:4326.  The project itself is set to 3857.  When exported to QGIS-Cloud, the map will display fine, etc.  When I leave the search feature set to OpenStreetMapSearch it works as expected, zooming to the named feature on OpenStreetMap. However, when I create a custom dbsearch that searches across various layers, the search works well, but when a name is selected (regardless of what name) it will zoom to 0,0 of the coast of Africa (where there is no feature).

I thought perhaps this was because of the two CRS - that the GIS server re-projects my custom layers on the fly but somehow the search does not.  But I re-projected one of my custom layers to 3857 and have the same result. I assume a reprojection changes the values in the wkb_geometry field but have not validated that (will do that now).

Lack possibly relevant fact, per qgis-cloud recommendations, I have restricted displayed CRS to the two used.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not an answer but just to point that reprojection does NOT changes the values in the wkb_geometry field, the only field that is modified by reprojection is the geometry field (usualy hidden from the attribute table or just displaying the geometry type). You will need to update your wkb_geometry field after reprojection

Comment: Thank you for this.  I found that if you export the layer as a new SHP file (changing from 4326 to 3857) it does update the wkb_geometry ... that was my initial solution.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration of the Custom Search is described in detail in the [QGIS Cloud Documentation](https://docs.qgiscloud.com/en/#user-sefined-search)?

Note that the CRS of the result column bbox must be the same as that of the project. In our example data, the points have a the CRS 4326 – that is, WGS84. If the published project is referenced in a different CRS, then the QGIS Cloud Web Client would move the map to the point’s bounding box in WGS84 Coordinates. But this is not true and the wrong section would be selected on the map. That’s why in this case you need to do a transformation of the points’ coordinates to the map’s CRS. Fortunately, PostGIS offers the appropriate function for this. The transformation can then be done as follows.

`... Box2D(st_transform(<geometry column>, <CRS>)) AS bbox`

Replace the () with the CRS of the published map.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great solution. I should have figured that PostGIS would have this sort of function.